# Area of brain tumor using binarization method

Tags: matlab, k-means, image-segmentation, medical

For my project, I segment the tumor cells from the normal brain cells using K-means algorithm and and find out the area using the below coding.

```
tumour_image;



binarized_img = zeros(n,n);
threshold = mean(tumour_image(:));
binarized_img(find(tumour_image>=threshold)) = 1;
binarized_img(find(tumour_image<threshold)) = 0;

n=512;
binarized_img = handles.binarized_img;
affected_img = imresize(binarized_img,[n/2 n/2]);
number_of_white_pixel = length(find(binarized_img == 1));
p=0.264;
size_tumour = sqrt(number_of_white_pixel)*p;
```

In the above code,the tumor image is subjected to thresholding process and i calculate the area using the above steps.I get this steps from [this](http://www.ijera.com/papers/Vol5_issue4/Part%20-%206/J504066065.pdf)  journal paper.

[image]

I have attached my tumor image as well,for this image I'm getting 33.321 mm2 as a tumor area.The problem now is,in the image,tumor part seems to be large,but I get this small value as area and in the code,to find the size of area,they use `sqrt`,is there any best way to find the area of tumor than this? or do i need to modify this square root to square vale.

Comment: Completely unrelated comment about the paper: 1) that paper is **very weak** as research method, honestly, really really weak.  2) That jounral is *absolutely* a predatory open access journal that works by scamming money from people that want to publish without having a real peer review. 

Independently on how well you can imitate that journal, any reputable institution will not accept it as a decent reference or work. Stay away from that type of journals. And there are better ways (in real journals) to do what you want to do

Comment: You are literally better off using region growing for this.

Comment: @Ander Biguri okey,thank you.Ill try,I found a similar article like this in IEEE explore also,so i thought it will be a good journal paper.

Comment: Please do not get offended (just in case) I mean the best for you. Using papers (and publishing papers) in these type of journals can damage seriously your reputation in academia.

Comment: Okey,can you please share a link to find the area of the tumor, im stuck in this part for so many days.

Comment: by area you mean the number of pixel ?

Comment: @ obchardon yea,i prefer it to be in mm2.

Comment: But so if I understand it's not really a problem with matlab, you're looking for an algorithm that can improve your detection, right ?

Comment: yea,that's right.first I thought to improve this code,but it seems not possible now.actually i need an algorithm to find the area of tumor.

Comment: @temp I told you already: region growing would do the job. Also, doing `tumour=Image>230` will also probably do the job.

Comment: ok,tumor=image>230 what's meant by this line